# How do I configure Eclipse to launch a browser when Run or Debug is selected using Pydev plugin

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I'm learning Python and Django using the Eclipse Pydev plugin. I want the internal or external browser to launch or refresh with the URL http:/127.0.0.1 when I press Run or Debug. I've seen it done with the PHP plugins but not Pydev.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the steps to set up an external launch configuration to launch IE:

1. Select **Run**->**External Tools**->**External Tools Configurations...**
2. In the left hand pane, select **Program** then the new icon (left-most icon above the pane).
3. In the right hand pane, select the **Main** tab.
4. Enter **launch_ie** in the **Name:** field.
5. Enter **${system_path:explorer.exe}** in the **Location:** field.
6. Enter **http:/127.0.0.1** in the **Arguments** field.
7. To run the external configuration, select **Run**.

If you want to share the configuration you can use these optional steps:

6. Select the **Common** tab
7. Select the **Shared file:** option in the **Save As** section.
8. Select a location to save the configuration (saving it to an otherwise empty project might be a good idea, as you can import that to another workspace)

To rerun the configuration you have a few choices:

1. Select the External Tools icon from the menu bar [image: external tools icon]
    then click **launch_ie**
2. Select **Run**->**External Tools**->**launch ie**
3. Hit Alt+R, E, 1 (assuming launch_ie is the first item in the list, otherwise pick the appropriate number)

Answer (score 1):

project properties (right click project in left pane)

Go to "run/debug settings", add a new profile. Setup the path and environment etc... you want to launch. The new configuration will show up in your build menu. You could also configure it as an "external tool"

Comment: I can't figure out how to do this.  Could you please be more specific?