# How to open the default browser from Eclipse user space on any platform?

Tags: eclipse, cross-platform

I want to select a term a term in the editor and pass it to an external URL using the default browser.

I found a few helpful hints on SO, especially [this recipe for invoking IE from an external tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697142/?answertab=votes#tab-top). But I would like to open the default browser, not necessarily IE, and not necessarily in Windows.

I answered the question below with a Windows-specific recipe, but given that [there are several recipes for launching the browser from the Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299806/), I figured there is also an user-visible variable for the browser, and I was just unable to find it. If you are able to find that, please answer the question. Or if you know that it is impossible to do so, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Eclipse has an internal browser, you dont want to use that?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078233/how-to-open-a-external-browser-in-eclipse-editor Not exact same question, but similar

Comment: Thanks @Fredrik. For completeness, it would be nice to see an answer for the internal browser. Personally, I prefer an external browser. The question 7078233 is very similar to the one I linked to in post, i.e., it offers an API-based method. I am looking for a user-space method.

Answer (score 1):

To open the default browser on Windows, use the `start` built-in command to `cmd.exe` with a URL. Below I have an example of the dialog you get when you go to Run, External Tools, External Tools Configurations... I compressed the left pane because it contains proprietary information from my company, but the part that matters is in the right pane.

Cygwin has a similar mechanism. You would not need the `/c` and `start` arguments. Instead you would use `${system_path:cygstart.exe}` for `Location` and only the url in `Arguments`. From my Ubuntu command-line, I can also run `xdg-open` in place of `cygstart.exe` to open the default browser. But I couldn't find a way that works the same in all platforms, although it seems to exist at the Eclipse API level.

[image: Win7/Juno dialog for opening the default brower]

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to have a ${default_browser} user-visible variable that would map to each of the various OS specific locations.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac you can use External tools and set the location to "/usr/bin/open" and in the arguments specify the path to the file you want to open:

[image]

Since the file is an HTML page, the default browser should open with it.